# How to remove an incomplete package by using apt-get?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I've tried to install android-studio via apt-get in Ubuntu and find that a dependency package with a size of 233 M is required to download from Google. Since I'm in China the network condition is so bad that I cannot download the package completely, and finally I have to give up.
  However here comes a problem: now every time I execute `apt-get` I will get a hint of `Incomplete dependency` and be asked to download the package above. If I execute `sudo apt-get remove android-studio` an error will occur:

```
dpkg: error processing package android-studio (--remove):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal
An error occurred when processing:
android-studio
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My `apt-get` was stuck. So how can I remove an incomplete package entirely?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try running following commands on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq tspc
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

These may clear or fix broken packages and try to install again.

Comment: As I executed `sudo apt-get autoremove` it told me that "A package will be upgrade: android-studio" and began to download. But as I've told above my network condition does not allow me to download such a enormous file from Google. So is there any other solutions  without requiring to fix the dependencies?

Comment: can you please try to execute third command first to remove broken package? let me know what you got.

Comment: Now it've been removed. Thank you very much!

Comment: How to check if it has been removed or not?

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install will try to insteall the damn thing, not remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Open [synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) Install synaptic. Then go to status and choose Broken. Then remove completely the broken packages.