# Removing broken packages in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

There was an error when I tried to remove a package, so it was left in a broken state. I tried the following:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq rvm
```

Output:

```
(Reading database ... 41743 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rvm (1.29.3-1) ...
bash: rvm: command not found
dpkg: error processing package rvm (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rvm
```

.

```
sudo dpkg --purge rvm
```

Output: same as above

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite package
```

Output:

```
dpkg: error processing archive rvm (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rvm
```

Is there a way to force remove it, ignoring all errors? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on WSL.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I faced this problem with a broken package, **rvm**. I tried many things like `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all rvm` but nothing worked. Finally I managed to find a blog post that explains how to remove broken packages on Debian/Ubuntu.

Here are the steps.

1. Find your package in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, for example using: `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep <package>`
2. Move the package folder to another location, like suggested in the blog post I mentioned before.

   ```
    sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.* /tmp/
   ```
3. Run the following command:

   ```
    sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package>
   ```

So as an example I solved my problem by executing the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/rvm.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq rvm
```

Comment: This worked for me, and also with a wedged package on WSL. Not sure how the other "how to install things" answers are relevant when the question is about removing a broken package.

Comment: Step 2 proved sufficient for my case.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me BIG TIME!. I am using ubuntu 18.04 under windows 10 (as WSL) and trying to install docker and your answer helps me while installing docker-ce package manually.

Comment: I had a problem because of some non-UTF8 characters that had somehow been inserted into /var/lib/dpkg/status file, causing broken package errors. I deleted those packages (along with the non-UTF8 characters) from the file, and then did Step 2. Solved my problem!

Comment: You don't need the `--force-remove-reinstreq` stuff, once those files are gone it's good...

Comment: sudo dpkg --purge --force-all <package-name> worked for me.

Comment: I was cured at `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all <package-name>`. You are my best friend now.

Comment: the pirpime website linked above is offline for the moment but it's archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201112035511/http://www.piprime.fr/1480/manually-remove-broken-package-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: This helped me in removing salt minion and it's leftover packages

Answer (score 2):

1. Install synaptic package manager.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```
2. Open synaptic package manager and search for the package which you want to remove or install or change

Done!

Comment: This does not answer the question! Rather, it's giving another way of installing packages.

Comment: Synaptic is different, and handles things differently. Sometimes synaptic fixes things apt doesn't. So it might actually be a proper answer..!

Comment: Not really a answer, people only face this problem because apt intall is no longer useable due to broken package, this offers a solution to a problem after you already fixed the problem. As you are not able to run apt-get install synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

so in my case `perl-modules-5.22` was corrupt.
I followed the steps in the accepted answer, but this did not resolve my issue.

to fix I additionally had to:

```sh
sudo apt remove -f perl-modules-5.22
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt remove -f <package_name>`

Ex: `sudo apt remove mongo*` will remove all mongo db packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where a package was missing files, and hence could not be removed. The error message was "Stopping Service. Cannot stop ***.service, service is not running"
Service is not running since service file is missing.

Shouldn't it be easier to purge the package then? I guess not.

Still: run aptitude

```
sudo aptitude
```

find the package in question, check its info, verify which versions exist.
Install a different version from the one you have presently (ideally one patch version up or down from what you have to avoid too much change) - it will ask you what to do with the missing files - choose to replace from the version being installed

```
sudo apt-get install <package>=<version>
```

Once all such missing files are replaced, you should be able to do standard purge

```
sudo apt-get purge <package>
```

Answer (score -8):

Execute the command as a root

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You need elevated privileges for the package manager.