# ROS2 (ros-eloquent-desktop) - Ubuntu 18.04 - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04** and I want to install ROS 2 from [Robot Operating System](https://www.ros.org/).
I am following instructions given in [Installing ROS 2 via Debian Packages](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/).
Based on this page **Eloquent Elusor** is the latest version for **ubuntu 18.04**.

I did [Setup Locale](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/#id2) and [Setup Sources](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/#id3) with no error. But, in [Install ROS 2 packages](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/#id4) when I enter

```
sudo apt install ros-eloquent-desktop
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-eloquent-desktop : Depends: ros-eloquent-depthimage-to-laserscan but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-eloquent-image-tools but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-eloquent-intra-process-demo but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-eloquent-pcl-conversions but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-eloquent-rqt-common-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-eloquent-rviz-default-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-eloquent-rviz2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is an issue that could have several causes, but is common. It may be that you installed Ubuntu 18, but haven't done an apt update/upgrade before installing ros. Or something else. The easiest suggestion is to search for how to deal with broken packages, in general; there's many articles out there.

Comment: Ex: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48726142/6069586)